# ZF2 : Change a row field in ResultSet

Tags: foreach, zend-framework2, buffer, resultset

I want to change a row field in my ResultSet before returning it to my Controller.

```
$resultSet->buffer();
foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
    $row->foo = $newvalue;
}
return $resultSet;
```

Problem is, when I use the buffer() function I can indeed loop over my ResultSet and make some changes on my rows, but once the loop ends all changes are gone.

I tried to set up a reference on $row :

```
foreach ($resultSet as &$row)
```

But then caught the following exception :

```
 Fatal error: An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference
```

I also tried to change resultSet to array but the same problem occurs.
Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible via the usual `ResultSet` usage. The array solution might work only if you are going to use the `array` in loops (foreach() in this case).

From any Table class -

```
$arr_resultSet = array();

foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
    $row->foo = $newvalue;

    //Object is assigned instead of converting it to an array.
    $arr_resultSet[] = $row;  
}
return $arr_resultSet;
```

Usage of this array in controller or view file -

```
//Here you can access that $row object as if the $resultSet was never converted to array.
foreach($arr_resultSet as $row) {
    echo $row->foo;                   
}
```

No need of `buffer()`. I hope it works for now. Will definitely search for a proper solution.

Comment: Wow. I tried to use toArray() function but then it was a mess because I had nested arrays instead of objects. Your solution is so simple I wonder how I missed it.
It works fine and seems a reasonable solution to me so I will already set it as answered. Anyway if you come up with a proper solution, I would be glad to look at it.
Many thanks :)